# Sitecore item:saved event handlers not being invoked on package installation

Tags: c#, events, sitecore, sitecore8

I've written an item:saved event handler which works fine for saving in the content editor. However, during a package installation, for new or existing items, the event handler is not invoked. What might be causing this? Thank you.

Comment: Try `item:created` instead

Comment: @MarekMusielak I can do that, but it wouldn't seem to trap item updates.

Comment: Use both of them, `item:saved` for updates and `item:created` for new items. And call same code in the background